# не выводится 3d объект в opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

Очень много времени трачу на этот код, пытаюсь найти ошибку, но не получается. Здесь есть функция, которая считывает модель из файла. Она вроде всё правильно считывает. Также у модели есть два вида отображения, с текстурой и без. Посмотрите пожалуйста, правильно ли я вывожу объект на сцену, правильно ли заданы параметры перспективы и т.д.

```
#include "model.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "vars.h"
#include "conf.h"
#include "gl.h"

extern struct conf cf;

Model::Model ( ) {
    this->frames = nullptr;
    this->texture = nullptr;

    float aspect = ( float ) cf.screen_width / ( float ) cf.screen_height;

    this->proj = glm::perspective ( glm::radians ( 45.f ), aspect, 0.1f, 100.f );
    this->view = glm::translate ( glm::mat4 ( 1.0f ), glm::vec3 ( 0.f, 0.f, 0.f ) );
    this->model = glm::mat4 ( 1.0f );
    this->rotate = glm::mat4 ( 1.0f );

    this->current_frame = 0;

    this->program_wit = cf.programs [ SHADER_MODEL_WITH_TEXTURE ];
    this->program_wiot = cf.programs [ SHADER_MODEL_WITHOUT_TEXTURE ];

    this->wit.sampler_location = gl::GetUniformLocation ( this->program_wit, "s_texture" );
    this->wit.transform_location = gl::GetUniformLocation ( this->program_wit, "transform" );
    this->wit.perspective_location = gl::GetUniformLocation ( this->program_wit, "perspective" );
    this->wit.rotate_location = gl::GetUniformLocation ( this->program_wit, "rotate" );

    this->wiot.transform_location = gl::GetUniformLocation ( this->program_wiot, "transform" );
    this->wiot.perspective_location = gl::GetUniformLocation ( this->program_wiot, "perspective" );
    this->wiot.rotate_location = gl::GetUniformLocation ( this->program_wiot, "rotate" );
}

void Model::transform ( const glm::vec3 &translate ) {
    this->view = glm::translate ( this->model, translate );
}

void Model::set_color ( glm::vec4 color ) {
    this->color = color;
}

void draw_with_texture ( Model *m ) {
    gl::UseProgram ( m->program_wit );

    gl::ActiveTexture ( gl::TEXTURE0 );
    gl::BindTexture ( gl::TEXTURE_2D, m->textureid );

    gl::Uniform1i ( m->wit.sampler_location, 0 );
    gl::UniformMatrix4fv ( m->wit.transform_location, 1, gl::FALSE_, &m->view[0][0] );
    gl::UniformMatrix4fv ( m->wit.perspective_location, 1, gl::FALSE_, &m->proj[0][0] );
    gl::UniformMatrix4fv ( m->wit.rotate_location, 1, gl::FALSE_, &m->rotate[0][0] );

    gl::EnableVertexAttribArray ( 0 );
    gl::EnableVertexAttribArray ( 1 );
    gl::EnableVertexAttribArray ( 2 );

    gl::VertexAttribPointer ( 0, 3, gl::FLOAT, gl::FALSE_, 0, m->frames[m->current_frame].v );
    gl::VertexAttribPointer ( 1, 3, gl::FLOAT, gl::FALSE_, 0, m->frames[m->current_frame].vn );
    gl::VertexAttribPointer ( 2, 2, gl::FLOAT, gl::FALSE_, 0, m->frames[m->current_frame].vt );

    gl::DrawArrays ( gl::TRIANGLES, 0, m->frames[m->current_frame].length_v );

    gl::DisableVertexAttribArray ( 0 );
    gl::DisableVertexAttribArray ( 1 );
    gl::DisableVertexAttribArray ( 2 );
}

void draw_without_texture ( Model *m ) {
    gl::UseProgram ( m->program_wiot );

    gl::UniformMatrix4fv ( m->wiot.transform_location, 1, gl::FALSE_, &m->view[0][0] );
    gl::UniformMatrix4fv ( m->wiot.perspective_location, 1, gl::FALSE_, &m->proj[0][0] );
    gl::UniformMatrix4fv ( m->wiot.rotate_location, 1, gl::FALSE_, &m->rotate[0][0] );

    gl::EnableVertexAttribArray ( 0 );
    gl::EnableVertexAttribArray ( 1 );
    gl::EnableVertexAttribArray ( 2 );

    gl::VertexAttribPointer ( 0, 3, gl::FLOAT, gl::FALSE_, 0, m->frames[m->current_frame].v );
    gl::VertexAttribPointer ( 1, 3, gl::FLOAT, gl::FALSE_, 0, m->frames[m->current_frame].vn );
    gl::VertexAttribPointer ( 2, 4, gl::FLOAT, gl::FALSE_, 0, &m->color[0] );

    gl::DrawArrays ( gl::TRIANGLES, 0, m->frames[m->current_frame].length_v );

    gl::DisableVertexAttribArray ( 0 );
    gl::DisableVertexAttribArray ( 1 );
    gl::DisableVertexAttribArray ( 2 );
}

void Model::switch_to ( ) {
    if ( this->texture ) this->map = draw_with_texture;
    else this->map = draw_without_texture;
}

void Model::draw ( ) {
    this->map ( this );
}

void Model::read_file ( const char *file ) {
    int count;

    char path[255] = { 0 };
    snprintf ( path, 254, "%s/models/%s", DEFAULT_ASSETS, file );
    FILE *fp = fopen ( path, "r" );
    fread ( &count, sizeof ( int ), 1, fp );
    this->frames = new struct frame [ count ];

    for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
        fread ( &this->frames[i].length_v,  sizeof ( unsigned int ), 1, fp );
        fread ( &this->frames[i].length_vt, sizeof ( unsigned int ), 1, fp );
        fread ( &this->frames[i].length_vn, sizeof ( unsigned int ), 1, fp );

        this->frames[i].v  = new float [ this->frames[i].length_v ];
        this->frames[i].vt = new float [ this->frames[i].length_vt ];
        this->frames[i].vn = new float [ this->frames[i].length_vn ];

        fread ( &this->frames[i].v[0],  sizeof ( float ), this->frames[i].length_v, fp );
        fread ( &this->frames[i].vn[0], sizeof ( float ), this->frames[i].length_vn, fp );
        fread ( &this->frames[i].vt[0], sizeof ( float ), this->frames[i].length_vt, fp );
    }

    fclose ( fp );
}
```

model.h

```
#include "../glm/glm.hpp"
#include "../glm/ext.hpp"
#include "sprite.h"
#include "object.h"

struct frame {
    unsigned int length_v;
    unsigned int length_vt;
    unsigned int length_vn;

    float *v;
    float *vn;
    float *vt;
};

struct with_t {
    int sampler_location;
    int transform_location;
    int perspective_location;
    int rotate_location;
};

struct without_t {
    int transform_location;
    int perspective_location;
    int rotate_location;
};

class Model : public Object {
    private:
        glm::mat4 proj;
        glm::mat4 view;
        glm::mat4 model;
        glm::mat4 rotate;
        glm::mat4 result;

        glm::vec4 color;


        struct frame *frames;

        unsigned int current_frame;

        unsigned int program_wit;
        unsigned int program_wiot;

        struct with_t wit;
        struct without_t wiot;

        unsigned int textureid;

        friend void draw_with_texture ( Model * );
        friend void draw_without_texture ( Model * );

        void (*map) ( Model * );

    public:
        Model ( );
        void read_file ( const char *file ) override;
        void draw ( ) override;
        void set_color ( glm::vec4 color );
        void switch_to ( void );
        void transform ( const glm::vec3 &translate );
        Sprite *texture;
};
```

А вот вершинный шейдер.

```
#version 400
layout ( location = 0 ) in vec3 position;
layout ( location = 1 ) in vec3 normaly;
layout ( location = 2 ) in vec4 color;
uniform mat4 transform;
uniform mat4 perspective;
uniform mat4 rotate;
out vec4 v_color;

void main ( )
{
  gl_Position = perspective * transform * vec4 ( position, 1.0 );
  v_color = color;
}
```

Вот фрагментный

```
#version 400
precision mediump float;
in vec4 v_color;
layout ( location = 0 ) out vec4 out_color;
void main ( )
{
  out_color = v_color;
}
```

Comment: Я сделал ещё спрайт, чтобы рисовать спрайты. Но спрайт тоже не видно. Странно очень. Я использовал glLoadGen для генерации opengl. Сишный проект с такими параметрами для спрайта рисует спрайт нормально. Что может быть не так? opengl команда перекрасить экран срабатывает, экран меняет цвет, а почему другое не рисует не пойму.

Comment: Можно попробовать ставить `glGetError` после каждой GL-функции. Еще можно попробовать запустить под [RenderDoc](https://renderdoc.org/).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat пишет        GL_INVALID_OPERATION
           The specified operation is not allowed in the current state. The offending command is ignored and has no other side effect than to set the error flag.

Comment: Какая именно функция выдает эту ошибку?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я решил сразу попробывать эту функцию, проверка проводится только этой функции. gl::DrawArrays

Comment: @HolyBlackCat gl::UseProgram тоже ошибку выводит INVALID_OPERATION.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я щас подумал что может быть дело в том, что я sdl поставил в версию opengl 4 3, хотя opengl генерировал такие исходники. Переключил sdl в версию 3.0 и спрайт стал виден.

Comment: но 3d объект не видно пока.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat блин, почему то от 3d объекта рисуется только один треугольник, а почему не понятно. Вообще странные дела какие то. Так не понятно, что хочется отказаться заниматься программированием графики. Думал что может в glfw получится, написал код, а он вообще не отображает даже треугольник. В основном проекте на sdl2, я пытаюсь создать куб из obj модели, координаты передаются правильные, я проверял. Создаю куб без текстуры с заданным цветом, но рисует только треугольник, но почему?

Comment: *"отказаться заниматься программированием графики"* Думаете, в других областях легче? *"Думал что может в glfw получится"* OpenGL работает одинаково и в glfw, и в sdl2. *"рисует только треугольник, но почему"* А я откуда знаю? Я же код не видел. Отлаживайте. Найдите ПЕРВУЮ функцию, на которую ругается glGetError и разберитесь почему.

Comment: Дальше, если `glGetError` больше не ругается, а картинка все еще неправильная, проверте, что valgrind, санитайзеры, и т.д. не ругаются на ваш код. Если и это не помогло, перепишите программу с нуля, в одном файле, без единого класса. Если и тогда не заработает - выкладывайте сюда. Если заработает - найдите что-нибудь, что умеет логировать вызовы GL функций, и сравнивайте логи для программ с классами и без.